# I can't connect to mysql?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[here is my code please help me to solve this prob.i think error is inside the function. compiler show error on line 9. thanks in advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrzcU.png)

```
<?php

class db_connector{
var $db_dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=erp5_temp2";
var $db_username = "root";
var $db_password = "";
var $dbh ="";

    public db_connector(){  
        $dbh = new PDO($this->$db_dsn,$this->$db_username,$this->$db_password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,TRUE);
    }
    public get_db_handler(){
        return $dbh;
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't described your error or what you are trying to do. Please edit your question to include those so someone can actually help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `function` keyword:

```
class ClassName
{
    public function methodName()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: aftr attaching function keyword it will terminate program

Comment: At least show the error code

Comment: Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. generate this error after attaching function

Comment: Ok, you are asking a route that does not exists.

Comment: nope path is correct because whenever i remove function keyword from program generate error .

Comment: Yes, but what error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `function` statement:

```
<?php

class db_connector{
    var $db_dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=erp5_temp2";
    var $db_username = "root";
    var $db_password = "";
    var $dbh ="";

    public function db_connector(){  
        $dbh = new PDO($this->$db_dsn,$this->$db_username,$this->$db_password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,TRUE);
    }
    public function get_db_handler(){
        return $dbh;
    }
}

?>
```